# How to provide Vaadin addon @StyleSheets for different themes

Tags: css, themes, vaadin, vaadin7

I created a widget, lets call it Vaadin addon, and included a css-file using the stylesheet annnotation: `@StyleSheet({ "custom.css" })`

Now I'm wondering how to handle the usage within different themes. My first idea was, to write the css like this:

```
.valo .mybutton { background: red;}
.reindeer .mybutton {background: yellow;}
```

The problem is, if my application theme extends the `reindeer` theme, the html will not contain any `reindeer` class name, same with `valo`. I didn't found documentation on this topic.. (what I read is [this post](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Packaging+SCSS+or+CSS+in+an+add-on))

Answer (score 1):

Is this the right approach though? You have to define look of your component for each theme available on your own and decide what is the best visual representation of your component in that given theme. If that theme changes, you have to change your add-on too. If there is new theme, you will have to update your component too.

More suitable approach might be just to use standard vaadin css classes, thus letting theme decide how your component will look. You just define structure of your component and logical parts from which it consists using standard vaadin classes. This way, your component will fit perfectly no matter what theme is used, also it is prepared for any number of new custom themes to be published. I do not say you should not include styles to your add-on, i just say you should consider not tying your add-on to any concerte themes.

Comment: I like your idea but I don't think that this is as easy to archive as it sounds. e.g. there is a textfield besides a button, in reindeer the text field is 24px height, in valo much higher. The default button height is the same in both themes it seems, so how would I archive a nice look and feel? i could add them in a layout and seht height 100% but this seems a lot of overhead. or do I miss sth?

Comment: Is there an other way to include css files than the annotation?